# 2d-transform - How to keep position?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, transform

I want to draw several perspective -transformed rectangles (shapes) in the lower right corner of a canvas. For this I used ctx.transform: `ctx.transform(1, 0, -1, 1, 10, 10)`.

Now I want to scale the size of my drawing using a variable `scale=n`, but still keep the position at exactly this point (in the center).

This is the code I wrote so far. Moving the slider changes the position of the shapes. How can I avoid this?

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
canvas.width = canvas.height = 200;
$(canvas).appendTo(document.body)
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")

let update = function(input) {
  let scale = input.value;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  ctx.transform(1, 0, -1, 1, 10, 10)
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    ctx.fillStyle = (i === 2) ? "#3b2a19" : "#957e67"
    let layer = {
      x: canvas.width + scale * 7 - i * scale,
      y: canvas.height - scale * 5 - i * scale,
      width: scale * 3,
      height: scale * 1.5
    }
    ctx.fillRect(layer.x, layer.y, layer.width, layer.height)
    ctx.strokeRect(layer.x, layer.y, layer.width, layer.height)
  }
  ctx.resetTransform();
}

$("input").trigger("input")
```

```css
#canvas {
  border: 2px solid red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

<input oninput="update(this)" type="range" min="1" max="20" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the transform I would recommend you to draw the shapes yourself.

See sample code below:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
canvas.width = canvas.height = 200;
$(canvas).appendTo(document.body)
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")

function shape(x,y,s) {
  var f = s/18
  ctx.moveTo(x-10*f, y-60*f);
  ctx.lineTo(x-110*f, y-60*f);
  ctx.lineTo(x-160*f, y-10*f);
  ctx.lineTo(x-60*f, y-10*f);
  ctx.lineTo(x-10*f, y-60*f);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
}

let update = function(input) {
  let scale = input.value;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  ctx.lineWidth = Math.min(scale/2, 2);
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = (i === 2) ? "#3b2a19" : "#957e67"
    shape(canvas.width, canvas.height -i * scale * 1.5, scale)
  }
}

$("input").trigger("input")
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid red }
input { position: absolute }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input oninput="update(this)" type="range" min="1" max="20" >
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: stroke needs to be scaled too

Comment: @Kaiido it is `ctx.lineWidth = Math.min(scale/2, 2);`

Answer (score 1):

Avoid so much calculations in your drawings.

All the shapes actually share the same constant width and height,   and a constant offset relative to the previous one in the stack.
The only real variable in there is the position of the camera.

So modify only this camera, and to do so, change only your context's transform matrix.

You'll need to

- translate the context to the first shape's origin
- scale the context by the current scale value
- skew the context by -1 on the Y axis
- draw your stack with constant values

The three first steps can be made in a single call to the absolute *setTransform* method.

The parameters will be,

```
setTransform(
  scale,    // scale-x
  0,        // skew-x
  - scale,  // skew-y (we use '- scale' here because skew should be made
            // after scale so we need to multiply by scale)
  scale,    // scale-y
  origin_x, // these should be made before so normal scale is ok
  origin_y
)
```

After that, the real drawing part will always be the same.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
canvas.width = canvas.height = 200;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
const input = document.querySelector('input');
function update() {
  // some constants about our shapes
  const origin_x = 160; // center of all the rects
  const origin_y = 160; // bottom of all the shapes
  const w = 33; // width of each rect
  const h = 16.5; // height of each rect
  const offset = 11; // axis offset (* i)
  const scale = input.value;
  
  // first reset the transformation matrix
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
  // so we clear everything
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  // now we move our context
  // so that our origins are in the top - left
  // and that we are already scaled and skewed
  ctx.setTransform(scale, 0, -scale, scale, origin_x, origin_y);
  
  // from now on, we don't care about the scale
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    ctx.fillStyle = (i === 2) ? "#3b2a19" : "#957e67"
    let layer = {
      x: -i * offset - w/2,
      y: -i * offset,
      width: w,
      height: h
    }
    ctx.fillRect(layer.x, layer.y, layer.width, layer.height)
    ctx.strokeRect(layer.x, layer.y, layer.width, layer.height)
  }
}
input.oninput = update;
input.oninput();
```

```css
#canvas {
  border: 2px solid red
}
input {
  display: block;
  width: 75vw;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="0.01" max="20" value="1" step="0.001" id="inp"/>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: "of a canvas". not of the stack of shapes. From OP *"but still keep the position at exactly this point (in the center)."* Anyway, that just a little modif to do in the constant drawing part (just change x and y and possibly origins) The answer stays the same.

Comment: what's the benefit of `const` inside the function?

Comment: Well they are constants so `const` should be used. They will be easier to optimize to the interpreter.

Comment: Since they are constants should's they be outside the function, so they memory is not allocated every time function runs?

Comment: Yes probably, but that also pollute the main scope. Not very important anyway.

Comment: Much thanks for your answer. Tbg @Kaiido is right: The Center Point shouldn‘t be the one of the Stack, it should be rather „of the Canvas“. Greetings

Comment: @jonas00 you mean as in http://jsfiddle.net/bw3rzmp4/ or as in the current answer?